# R fill a 3D array by repeating a matrix

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, multidimensional-array

I'm currently trying to find a quick way to solve my problem in R without using a loop.

I have a matrix A which is of size N x m.

I would like to obtain from it an array B which is of size N*m*5, where B[,,i]=A for all 0 < i < 6.

I have tried unsuccessfully to use the rep function, but I can't get it to output an 3D array.
Is there a way to do so, or should I just assign every value by hand ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `B[,,i]=A` for all 0 ?  Have you tried `replicate(5, A)`

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it, it had been cut out.
I tried what you said, it works, thank you very much it is exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `replicate` to get the output as an `array`

```
replicate(5, A)
```

Comment: Exactly what is needed

Answer (score 0):

You can just wrap `array` arround the matrix and "extend" the needed number of dimensions as the last entry in the `dim`-argument, and the matrix values will get "recycled":

```
B <- array( matrix(1:6, 2, 3), c(2,3,5) )
```